# spservices or JSOM SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'documentGetElementsByName' is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I receive the following error when I run my code in SharePoint 2010 site.  I am using JSOM and spservices. Below is an excerpt of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveData, "sp.js");
//'SP.ClientContext',
itemProjectNumber = getQueryString('projNumber');          
//Check to see if project number exist. If so, change buttons to update from submit
getID(itemProjectNumber, "Procurement Plan (Design)", part2);
});

var part2 = function (itemIDPPD) {
console.log(itemIDPPD);   //<--- UNDEFINED so it causes an error in other places.
if (itemIDPPD) {
    //alert(itemIDPPD);
    $("#design_procPlan").hide();
    $("#updDesign_procPlan").show();
}
.....
 function getID(pid, category, callback) {
var qry = "<Query><Where>" +
                 "<And>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
                        "<Value Type='Choice'>" + category + "</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
                        "<Value Type='Text'>" + pid + "</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                "</And>" +
              "</Where>" +
          "</Query>";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: true,
    listName: "Project Projections",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
                 "</ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: qry,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
        itemID = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("z\\:row, row").attr("ows_ID");
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            callback(itemID);
        }
    }
});
}
```

If it helps you can log into the site below and use the developer tool.
Here's a temp login information

http://iwebarea.com/SitePages/projectPlan.aspx?projNumber=adfadfadf

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my JSOM call to my SharePoint list.  I was able to find out by stripping my code and putting it into jsfiddle to pinpoint what the problem was.  https://jsfiddle.net/isogunro/g2cr896a/